# Why are the Differential- and multiplication mapping on $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $\Omega\neq\varnothing$ and suppose we have the Fréchet topology on $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ (this can be obtained by the topology construction from out seminorms). Let $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ ($\alpha_i\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$). Define the operator $D^{\alpha}:C^{\infty}(\Omega)\rightarrow C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ by:
$$f\mapsto \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\right)^{\alpha_{1}}\dots \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\right)^{\alpha_n}f$$
The first assertion is that this map is continuous. But how to start? If we can prove that $D^{\alpha}$ is continuous in $0$ then we are done, but how to show that? Questions about continuity are difficult from my point of view -.-

The second statement is that the multiplication of $f\in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ with a fixed $\varphi\in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is continuous. But why is that the case? how to begin?

Thank you for all help and proves :-)

Comment: Could you please state for us what is necessary to prove, in order to guarantee the continuity of such operator?

Comment: What do you mean? It is nessecary to prove that the mapping $D^{\alpha}$ is continuous. Or what is your question precisely?

Comment: How do you prove continuity?

Comment: By showing that every preimage of an open set is open of by showing: for all neighborhoods $V$ of $f(x)$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$

Comment: In this particular case, there is more easy ways to do this. Do you know any of them? It is related with the seminorms.

Comment: I know that per construction all seminorms are continuous

Comment: Let's do better. 1 - Write down all the seminors. 2 - Use the seminorms to induce a topology on $C^\infty(\Omega)$. 3 - Ask yourself how to prove continuity of such operators by using the semi norms. Also, take a look on the section examples here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space

Comment: Are you taking the Mastermath course in functional analysis by any chance?

Comment: What do you mean??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\Omega =\cup_{i=1}^\infty K_i$ where $K_i\subset \Omega$ are compact sets and $K_i\subset K_{i+1}$. For each $n$ and each multi-index $\alpha=(j_1,...,j_n)$, define the family of seminorms: $$\|u\|_{\alpha,j}=\sup\{|D^\alpha u(x)|:\ x\in K_j\} \tag{1}$$

We can enumarate the family of seminorms and induce the a Fréchet topology in $C^\infty (\Omega)$ by considering the metric $$d(u,v)=\sum _{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i}\frac{\|u-v\|_i}{1+\|u-v\|_i},\ \forall u,v\in C^\infty(\Omega)$$

With respect to this toplogy, we have that $u_n\to u$ in $C^\infty(\Omega)$ if and only if $d(u_n,u)\to 0$ and this is equivalently to say that $\|u-v\|_i\to 0$ for each $i=1,2,...$ and this is equivalently to say that $D^\alpha u_n$ converges to $D^\alpha u$ uniformly in each compact set $K_n$, for all multi-index $\alpha$ (also in each compact set contained in $\Omega$).

Now you have a more tractable way do prove your statements.

Comment: Thank you, thats a good idea to begin with :)

Comment: @Ricardo: I just reading books and make exercises to involve myself in this topic. I namely want to do this is my script (i just do an introduction course)

Comment: I'm also making this exercise. Is it correct in showing that $D^{\alpha}$ is continuous in proving that if $\|u_n\|_i \to 0$ that $\|D^{\alpha}u_n\|_i \to 0$ for all $i=1,2,3,...$?

Comment: Yes @user47709, it is. Do you know why?

Comment: Since $\|u_n\|_i\to 0$ on $K_i$ for each $i$ we also have that  $\|u_n\|_{i+\alpha}\to 0$ on $K_{i+\alpha}$. Now $K_i \subset K_{i+\alpha}$, it follows that $\{\sup |D^{i+\alpha}u_n|\}\to 0$ on $K_i$ and this is the same as saying that $\|D^{\alpha} u_n\|_i\to 0$. Is this correct @Tomás?

Comment: @user47709, the idea is correct, but you have to be careful with the notation, because $\alpha$ stands for a multi-index while $i$ is a natural number, hence $i+\alpha$ does not make sense.

Comment: I did do that in my notes however by replacing $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|$ when needed, so for $\|u_n\|_{i+|\alpha|}$ and $K_{i+|\alpha|}$ @Tomás .

Comment: The seminorms in Rudin are defined as $p_N(f)=\max \{|D^{\alpha}f(x)|:x \in K_N, |\alpha| \leq N\}$, does this coincide with the above definition?

Comment: Yes @user47709, they will generate the same topology.